SwiftUI .keyboardShortcut unexpectedly captured value inside Button's action
Here is a minimal test project I made:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var number: Int? = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        if let number {
            Button("Test") {
                print("number: \(number)")
                self.number! += 1
            }
            .keyboardShortcut("w", modifiers: [])
        }
    }
}

when pressing "w" key, "number: 0" is printed as expected, but when I press "w" again, it also print the same thing. On the other hand, when actually tapping the Button, the printed number does go up.
I think .keyboardShortcut should have the same action with the button's action, but seems like button action called by .keyboardShortcut doesn't re-evaluate variables from the View, is this considered a bug of SwiftUI?
I know I can unwrap the optional number inside Button's action closure and everything will be fine, but if I have 10 buttons, I will have to do this 10 time instead of 1.
I found out that I can unwrap the optional inside the Button to prevent this problem:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var number: Int? = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        if let number {
            Button("Test") {
                if let number = self.number {
                    print("number: \(number)")
                    self.number! += 1
                }
            }
            .keyboardShortcut("w", modifiers: [])
        }
    }
}

But in reality, there would be a lot variables and potentially many Buttons with keyboardShortcut, I can't prevent myself forgetting about this behaviour in the future, and adding another problematic Button, for example:
Button("Test2") {
    print("sum: \(number + number)")
}
.keyboardShortcut("e", modifiers: [])

one way to prevent this is removing outer if let check, but now I will need to unwrap inside every button:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var number: Int? = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Test") {
            if let number = self.number {
                print("number: \(number)")
                self.number! += 1
            }
        }
        .keyboardShortcut("w", modifiers: [])
        
        Button("Test2") {
            print("sum: \(number! + number!)")
        }
        .keyboardShortcut("e", modifiers: [])
    }
}

if there are dozen of Buttons, and the optional variable can be nil in some point, then I have to do dozen of if let check inside each Button, which will work, but is very annoying. It would be nice if there is a better way.
p.s. I am using macOS 15.1 & Xcode 16.1 beta, and run above code in a new mac app project.
